# 301 Редирект с одного домена второго уровня на другой

Tags: redirect, apache, хостинг, dns, домен

Здравствуйте.

В администрировании я новичок, поэтому прошу помощи.

Имеется выделенный сервер (apache) на bitnami, на нем несколько приложений.
Так вот, необходимо с НазваниеСайта.рф (только что созданный домен) сделать 301 редирект на SiteName.ru. Оба сайта имеют один статический адрес.

На сервере создан файл virtualhosts.conf со следующим содержанием:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
    ###########
    Alias /mediawiki/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/"
    Alias /mediawiki "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs"
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs"
        ServerName SiteName.ru
    </VirtualHost>
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs">
        Options +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/conf/htaccess.conf"
 ......
```

Данный файл включается в httpd.conf

Попытки вставить в virtualhosts.conf и httpd.conf следующее не привели к успеху:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} НазваниеСайта.рф
RewriteRule (.*) http://SiteName.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Может, что-то неправильно или непонятно объяснил, задавайте наводящие вопросы, буду пытаться дополнить, ответить. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему, сконфигурировав virtualhosts.conf, следующим образом:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

### НазваниеСайта.рф ###
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs"
    ServerName НазваниеСайта.рф
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://SiteName.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>

### SiteName.ru ###
Alias /mediawiki/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/"
Alias /mediawiki "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs"
    ServerName SiteName.ru
   </VirtualHost>
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/conf/htaccess.conf"
```

Скорее всего есть более изящное решение, но пока что так работает :)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xn--80aaaahtlkl6ae4cp\.xn--p1ai$
RewriteRule (.*) http://SiteName.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`xn--80aaaahtlkl6ae4cp.xn--p1ai` — это punycode для названиесайта.рф
Таким образом работает редирект для кириллических доменов.
punycode для своего домена можно посмотреть **[вот тут](http://2ip.ru/punycode/)**

Comment: Нужная вещь, спасибо